# Альтернативное решение - поиск арифметического среднего

Tags: python

```
import random
a=[]
s=0
for i in range(10):
    a.append(round((random.random() +9.0),2))
    s=s+a[i]
s=s/10
print(a)
print(round(s, 2))
```

Можно ли как нибудь решить через average и список? Суть в том, чтобы среди 10 чисел от 9.0 до 10.0 найти среднее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого не хватит?

```
a=[round((random.random() +9.0),2) for _ in range(10)]
s = sum(a)/len(a)
```

Comment: спасибо большое!